# Best way to combine Authorization.Forms and Authorization.Token in same project?

Tags: c#, nancy

What would be the best approach to securing modules with either Form of Token authorization in Nancy, in the same project? I need both types of security and I prefer not to create to separate apps: one with views secured with Form, and one for an API returning JSON using Token.

I am new to nancy and I just ported a MVC 5 app to nancy. So far I am not looking back! :-). Love the simple approach.

Any way, I would like to hear your ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you. Inspired by your suggestion I came up with the following code:

```
    protected override void RequestStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines, NancyContext context)
    {
        base.RequestStartup(container, pipelines, context);
        if (context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].SingleOrDefault() == null)
        {
            //no Authorization header found / request cannot be authenicated using token authentication. Enable Form authentication.
            var formsAuthConfiguration = new FormsAuthenticationConfiguration()
            {
                RedirectUrl = "~/user/login",
                UserMapper = container.Resolve<IUserMapper>()
            };
            FormsAuthentication.Enable(pipelines, formsAuthConfiguration);
        }
        else
        {
            //Authorization header found. Enable Token authentication.
            TokenAuthentication.Enable(pipelines, new TokenAuthenticationConfiguration(container.Resolve<ITokenizer>()));
        }           
    }
```

This works :-)

Comment: All of my authentication configuration currently is in ApplicationStartup.  Do you configure anything for authentication now in ApplicationStartup, or did you move everything into RequestStartup?

Comment: No, nothing in appstartup :-)

Comment: One last comment I just realized (the hard way): when you want to request a token through an API call (passing a username and password through a request), instead of using FormsAuthentication (posting a form), make sure to give the Authorization header of the API request a simple value (e.g. "Token request") to make sure that nancy enables TokenAuthenication. If you don't nancy will answer the API call using FormAuthenication, returning whatever you have setup to return when trying to login using FormsAuthencation, messing up your callback on the client

Answer (score 2):

If you create a single page aplication with Nancy and AngujarJS (for example) you only need to use Token authentication. (I recommend this)

You can enable both methods in the bootstraper with this code (this code is for enable  Forms authentication and  Basic authentication)

(This works but is not an elegant solution in my opinion)

```
protected override void RequestStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, Nancy.Bootstrapper.IPipelines pipelines, NancyContext context)
    {
        base.RequestStartup(container, pipelines, context);

        var credentials = ExtractCredentialsFromRequest(context);
        if(credentials !=null)
            context.CurrentUser = container.Resolve<IUserValidator>().Validate(credentials[0], credentials[1]);
    }

    private string[] ExtractCredentialsFromRequest(NancyContext context)
    {
        var authHeader = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].SingleOrDefault();
        if (authHeader == null)
            return null;

        var credentials = authHeader.Split(new[]{':'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (credentials.Length != 2)
            return null;

        return credentials;
    }
```

There is another option ( I never used it) Is a nuget package for hibryd auth for nancy

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nancy.Authentication.HybridStatelessAuthorizationHeaderAndForms/